# Java code does not work, gives me an error on eclipse

Tags: java, swing

The only error eclipse is giving me is: `errors exist in this project/s`. The code worked fine until I added the new class.

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Helloworld {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ();

        class HelloComponent extends JComponent{
            public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
                g.drawString("Hello, Java", 123, 95);
                frame.add(new HelloComponent());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _Did you read the errors_?

Comment: You can't define a new class in your main method.

Comment: @tobias_k [why not](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3), may I ask (specifically _Example 8.1.3-2. Inner Class Declarations_)?

Comment: I thought that initially as well, but I just tested and it's possible. Not my favorite feature of java...

Comment: @BoristheSpider Oh, my, I did not know this feature. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 4):

Your error is: *"Cannot refer to a non-final variable frame

inside an inner class defined in a different method"*.
You can fix it by defining `frame` as final.

`final JFrame frame = new JFrame();`

This is your compile time problem. Then you may need to
fix your code further if it does not do what you expect.

Comment: I think the line with `frame.add` just belongs in another line (directly in the main method), then `frame` does not need to be `final`, as well.

Comment: @tobias_k you are absolutely right - creating a `new HelloComponent` and adding it to the `frame` each time `paint` is called probably isn't what the OP intended.